# How to save an array of Web Api data to a child - parent schema in a nested mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to save the result of the Web Api which contains multiple arrays of data to populate the stock chart. Each time I enter a symbol and click the "Get Quote" button it should fetch data from the web api, save it under the Child Schema in the database. 
How can I do this with nodejs and mongoose? Here is the code that I tried....

**Folder - Models - Stock.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', { useNewUrlParser: true })
const slug = require('slug')


const childSchemaData = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: mongoose.Decimal128,
  open: mongoose.Decimal128,
  high: mongoose.Decimal128,
  low: mongoose.Decimal128,
  close: mongoose.Decimal128,
  volume: mongoose.Decimal128
})

const parentSchemaSymbol = new mongoose.Schema({
  symbol: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 4,
    required: 'Plese enter a valid symbol, min 2 characters and max 4'
  },
  // Array of subdocuments
  data: [childSchemaData],
  slug: String

});

//we have to PRE-save slug before save the parentSchemaSymbol into DB
parentSchemaSymbol.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified('symbol')) {
    next()//skip it
    return//stop this function from running
  }
  this.slug = slug(this.symbol)
  next()
  //TODO make more resiliant soslug are unique
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Stock', parentSchemaSymbol)
```

**Controller - webApiController.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const axios = require('axios')

require('../models/Stock')
const parentSchemaSymbol = mongoose.model('Stock')



mongoose.Promise = global.Promise // Tell Mongoose to use ES6 promises
// Connect to our Database and handle any bad connections
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', { useNewUrlParser: true })
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`        → ${err.message}`)
})

exports.webApi = (req, res) => {
  let curValue = req.params.symbol

  axios.get(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=${curValue}&outputsize=compact&apikey=TUVR`)
    .then(response => {
      return highLow = Object.keys(response.data['Time Series (Daily)']).map(date => {
        return [
          Date.parse(date),
          Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['1. open']) * 100) / 100,
          Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['2. high']) * 100) / 100,
          Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['3. low']) * 100) / 100,
          Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['4. close']) * 100) / 100,
          parseInt(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['5. volume'])
        ]
      })

    })
    .then(_ => {
      let curValueSchema = new parentSchemaSymbol()
      curValueSchema.symbol = curValue;
      curValueSchema.data.push(highLow);
      curValueSchema.slug = 'String';
      curValueSchema.save().then(doc => {
        console.log('Saved the symbol', doc)
        res.send(highLow)
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
}
```

**web api result = highLow**

[image]

Comment: how about you change `module.exports = mongoose.model('Stock', (childSchemaData, parentSchemaSymbol))` to  `module.exports = mongoose.model('Stock',  parentSchemaSymbol)` and save`highLowData` as `curValueSchema.data.push(highLowData)`  , see if that helps you

Comment: @siddhantsankhe You mean like this `let highLowData = highLow
let curValueSchema = new parentSchemaSymbol({
  symbol: curValue,
  data: [curValueSchema.data.push(highLowData)],
  slug: String
})` It gives me an error  `ReferenceError: parentSchemaSymbol is not defined
    at axios.get.then.then._ (/mnt/c/Users/john/Desktop/node/controllers/webApiController.js:34:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:7)

    `

Comment: please change statement to this `module.exports = mongoose.model('Stock', parentSchemaSymbol)` and after `require('../models/Stock')` please add `var parentSchemaSymbol = mongoose.model('parentSchemaSymbol');`

Comment: You dont need to export subdocument , and mongoose allows only one schema per export , if you are using sub document then it is already present in Parent Document exporting it separately would make whole point of using subdocuments pointless , regards

Comment: @siddhantsankhe you are right , very valid point . I updated the code but still getting the same error `const parentSchemaSymbol = mongoose.model(parentSchemaSymbol)
                                          ^

ReferenceError: parentSchemaSymbol is not defined`

Comment: Add quotes too ,const parentSchemaSymbol = mongoose.model('parentSchemaSymbol')

Comment: And again for saving data the `highLow` change code to this `let curValueSchema = new parentSchemaSymbol()
curValueSchema.symbol = curValue;
curValueSchema.data.push(highLow);
curValueSchema.slug =  'String';
curValueSchema.save()//rest of stuff`

Comment: @siddhantsankhe updated the code and the error

Comment: my mistake we have registered schema to `module.exports =mongoose.model('Stock', parentSchemaSymbol)` name`Stock` so which means `const parentSchemaSymbol=mongoose.model('Stock')` , changes to this , this should solve it

Comment: @siddhantsankhe it worked!!! but now I am getting a different error ;))))

Comment: wait ill upload proper code for you , u seem to have lots of errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183687/discussion-between-siddhant-sankhe-and-john-john).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at your axios request call , and change it to this

```
axios.get(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=${curValue}&outputsize=compact&apikey=TUVR`)
.then(response => {
  return highLow = Object.keys(response.data['Time Series (Daily)']).map(date => {
    return {
      data :Date.parse(date),
      open : Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['1. open']) * 100) / 100,
      high :Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['2. high']) * 100) / 100,
      low : Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['3. low']) * 100) / 100,
      close : Math.round(parseFloat(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['4. close']) * 100) / 100,
      volume : parseInt(response.data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['5. volume'])
    }
  })

})
.then(_ => {

  let curValueSchema = new parentSchemaSymbol()
  curValueSchema.symbol = curValue;

for(x in highLow){

    curValueSchema.data.push(highLow[x])
}

  curValueSchema.save().then(doc => {
    console.log('Saved the symbol', doc)
    return res.send(highLow)
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
  })
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

And in Schema i dont know what `this.slug = slug(this.symbol)` this does , but to use that slug method u must define it or import it , otherwise it will just give to errors , hope this helps you